# Posting all the Values in the table to Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to store the attendance of class1 into database but all the values are not inserted.

In my Form page

I populated all the students of class1 by their firstname using MySql query . Then have included additional columns for marking attendance and Writing Comments.

Everything works fine but only the last student values are Posted in database.

Form Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    connected to db    
<title>grade1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"><font color="white"><b>ATTENDANCE FOR GRADE1</font></b></h1>
2014-02-04 
<font color='orange' size=18px>class Id: grade1<br/>Teacher Id: 1<br>
location Id:502
</font> 
<table id="attendance" border="1"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" >
<tr >
<th>studentid</th>
<th width="150">Flag</th>
<th>comments</th>
</tr>
connected to db

<form action=insertattend.php method=POST> 
<tr><td align=center><input align=center name=fname[] type=text readonly value=udhayan   
</td>
<td><select name=flag[]>
<option value=none >--Mark attendance--<option value=present>Present
<option value=absent>Absent</select></td>
<td><textarea name=comment[] ></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align=center><input align=center name=fname[] type=text readonly value=Wade  
     </td>
<td><select name=flag[]>
<option value=none >--Mark attendance--<option value=present>Present
<option  value=absent>Absent</select></td>
<td><textarea name=comment[] ></textarea>  </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value=submit></td></tr>    
</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP Post code is:

```
    Array
(
[0] => udhayan
[1] => Wade
)
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' 
cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: 
#cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: 
sql in C:\wamp\www\app34\teacher\insertattend.php on line <i>13</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' 
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th     
align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' 
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' 
align='center'>0.0035</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>375392</td><td 
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\app34\teacher\insertattend.php'   
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\insertattend.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>

Query was empty
```

Comment: Add `</form>` tag in your `while` loop. `<form>` is starting in the `While` loop, but not ending in `While`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your form has duplicate names so only one is sent. to alleviate this problem, sent use arrays for the field names ie..

```
<input align=center name=fname[] type=text  
        value=" .$row['fname']." </td>
```

notice the change *fanme is now fname[]* now you can send an array of information instead of only sending the one field, repeat for the other fields.

also you need to start the form before the while loop, as another commenter pointed out.

Comment: No Change - Even the last student values is not stored

Comment: you need to change the way you process the post information $_POST['fname'] is now an array and not a string

Comment: no, it will be like $_POST['fname'][0], $_POST['fname'][1]... $_POST['fname'][n]

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in insertattend.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Because your  `<form>` tag is inside while loop. And `</form>` outside while loop. So when the loop finish it's work your form only contains last student's information. And also you need to insert attendance details by using loop. Then you need to **close** your `<input>` tag of  name.

Ok look a sample example. Here is a table named **student** which has two fields name and id. just try.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Connection error');
    mysql_select_db('test',$con);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  student");

 ?>
    <table>
        <form method='post' action='#'>

                <tr><td>Name</td><td>Attnd</td><td>Comment</td></tr>
                <?php
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td>
                            <td>
                            <select name='status_".$row['id']."'>
                            <option value='present'>Present</option><option value='Absent'>absent</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='comment_".$row['id']."'></td></tr>";
                    }
                 ?>

            <tr><td><input type='submit'></td></tr>
        </form>
    </table>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST) )
        { 
            $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  student");

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
            {
                $status=$_POST['status_'.$row['id']];
                $comment=$_POST['comment_'.$row['id']];
                echo $qry="INSERT INTO attendance( studentid, flag, comments) VALUES($row[id], $status, $comment)";
            }

        }
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u Pls check and tell still im not getting output

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean   insertattend.php on line 7 but values not stored

Comment: This is just a demo code. Here table structure and query are different. This code is works on my system.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the answer from Bryan and modify your code:-

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST['fname'] AS $key=>$fname)
    {
        $stfn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'][$key]);
        $cmt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'][$key]);
        $fg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['flag'][$key]);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance( studentid, flag, comments) VALUES('$stfn', '$fg', '$cmt')";
        echo $sql."<br />";
        mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}

echo "<br>";
echo "values inserted successfully!!!!";
?>
```

Note that Bryan deserves the credit for this.`enter code here`

Comment: Great values inserted sucessfully but not seen in attendance table

Comment: Have you made the other fields on the form (flag and comment) arrays as well by adding [] after their names?

Comment: Try it now with the debugging info in place

Comment: In what way was it empty? No values, or just some values? Or no query at all?

Comment: Qury executed returning an empty row

Comment: It is an insert that is being done, it shouldn't be returning a row. Is the insert giving an error? What has the echo of the sql put out?

Comment: Udefined variale sql.                                                            Query was empty

Comment: Where are you outputting it? That suggests it has never got into the loop so either $_POST['submit'] was not set or $_POST['fname'] was not an array. Try doing a print_r($_POST); before the loop and see what that outputs.

Comment: It shows array[o] -> student1 array[1]->student2. I think its because the submit button is outside the loop. Is there any other way to bring output

Comment: Can you update your original post with the form as it stands now? You should not have any input field called 0 in $_POST. The submit button should not be in the loop. Also commentbox is not a valid html input field type.

Comment: That doesn't go with $_POST you are getting (except we now have a random values line which will cause an error). Execute the page, do a view source and copy / paste the source above so we can see exactly the form that it is trying to submit.

Comment: 1 minor issue is that the form start tag is within the table but the form end tag is outside the table. This probably isn't a problem but will cause html validation issues. However your fname input fields, which is probably corrupting the input.

Comment: Thanks for the response - Have rectified the minor issue. Is there any other way or to change the entire code.

Comment: Add the closing tags to the fname input fields

Comment: Closed still the problem persists.

Comment: Think readonly will also prevent the field values being passed back with the form. Change them from being read only fields.

Comment: Should i change mySql as MySqli

Comment: Yes, but that is irrelevant to the issues you are having